# Is there a reference for the full list of Windows 10 'Shell Icon' numbers?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, icons, windows-shell

I'm looking for a reference that lists the possible entries under the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons
```

Entries under this registry key override the default icon used for various purposes in the Windows UI. Looking online I've found two so far:

- 29 - Shortcut Arrow overlay icon
- 179 - "Blue arrows" icon overlay for compressed files

Presumably Microsoft would have this list somewhere, but finding a comprehensive reference for Windows 10 has eluded me so far.

---

### Edit

I did some more experimenting by adding more number keys and pointing each to a unique icon. Here's the associations I've found so far:

```
3     normal folder icon
8     fixed drive folder icon
11    removable drive folder icon
15    network drive icon in the explorer address bar
29    shortcut overlay icon
34    explorer navigation pane root icon labelled 'Desktop'
51    network folder icon
77    UAC (administrator) overlay icon
107   os drive folder icon
179   compressed file/folder overlay icon
```

Comment: They are stored in "shell32.dll" file in the system32 folder, cant find a list either.Some discussion on how to see the icons in the dll.....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435/how-do-you-get-the-icons-out-of-shell32-dll

Answer (score 11):

Copy shell32.dll and imageres.dll in the System32 folder to a folder of choice, then use 7-Zip or other archiver to unpack the dll file, once that is done dig into the .rsrc folder to find the ICON folder, in there you will find the icons and numbers.

The registry entry should you wish to create one would look something like this

"DisplayIcon"="C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll,9"

or

"DisplayIcon"="C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll,9"

[image]

Comment: The "Icon" tab is provided by a third-party shell extension called "IconViewer".

Comment: This didn't work for me. I extracted the `C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll` with 7-zip. But the extracted folder contains no ICON folder, nor any .ico files or anything resembling icons.

Comment: Are your hidden files and folders unhidden? Do this in folder options

Comment: @birgersp latest Windows 10 builds are using *.MUN files for storing resources, which are located in C:\Windows\SystemResources\\*.mun -- that said, for the file `C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll` correct resource file path would be `C:\Windows\SystemResources\shell32.dll.mun` and you should be able to extract it the same way with 7-Zip.

Answer (score 5):

0 Explorer
1 Explorer Default Document
2 Explorer Default Application
3 Explorer Closed Folder
4 Explorer Open Folder
5 Drive 5.25 inch floppy
6 Drive 3.5 inch floppy
7 Drive Removable Drive
8 Drive Hard Drive
9 Drive Network Drive
10 Drive Network Drive disconnected
11 Drive CD-ROM Drive
12 Drive RAM Drive
13 Global Entire network
15 Explorer Networked Computer
16 Explorer Printer(s)
17 Desktop Network Neighborhood
18 Explorer Workgroup
19 Startmenu Programs
20 Startmenu Recent documents
21 Startmenu Settings
22 Startmenu Find
23 Startmenu Help
24 Startmenu Run
25 Startmenu Suspend
26 Startmenu Docking
27 Startmenu Shutdown
28 Overlay Sharing
29 Overlay Shortcut
31 Desktop Recycle bin empty
32 Desktop Recycle bin full
33 Explorer Dial-up Networking
34 Explorer Desktop
35 Startmenu Settings/Control Panel
36 Startmenu Programs/Program folder
37 Startmenu Settings/Printers
39 Startmenu Settings/Taskbar
40 Explorer Audio CD
42 Explorer Saved search (.fnd)
43 Explorer und Startmenu Favorites
44 Startmenu Log Off
77 UAC (administrator) overlay icon
107 os drive folder icon
179 compressed file/folder overlay icon

Comment: where are the rest ?

Answer (score 1):

```
1 // default file icon
2 // default document
3 // default exe file
4 // closed folder
5 // opened folder
6 // 5 1/4 disk
7 // 3 1/2 disk
8 // other removeable media
9 // hard drive
10 // network drive
11 // disconnected network drive
12 // cd-rom drive
13 // ram drive
14 // network (globe)
15 // network (mouse)
16 // my computer
17 // printer
18 // network computer
19 // entire network
20 // program group
21 // my recent documents
22 // control panel
23 // find
24 // help
25 // run
26 // good night (old log off?)
27 // undock
28 // shutdown
29 // shared
30 // shortcut
31 // scheduled task overlay
32 // recycle bin empty
33 // recycle bin full
34 // telephony
35 // desktop
36 // old settings
37 // program group, same as 20
38 // old printer
39 // fonts
40 // taskbar properties
41 // music cd
42 // tree
43 // old computer folder
44 // favorites
45 // log off
46 // find in folder
47 // windows update
48 // lock
49 // computer app ?
50 // empty - ignore
51 // empty - ignore
52 // empty - ignore
53 // empty - ignore
54 // old mistery drive
133 // file stack
134 // find files
135 // find computer glyph
137 // control panel, same as 22
138 // printer folder
139 // add printer
140 // network printer
141 // print to file
142 // old recycle bin full
143 // old recycle bin full of folders
144 // old recycle bin full of folders and files
145 // can't copy (overwrite?) file
146 // move to folder
147 // old rename
148 // old settings copy
151 // ini file
152 // txt file
153 // bat file
154 // dll file
155 // font file
156 // true type font file
157 // other font file
160 // run, same as 25
161 // old delete
165 // copy to disk
166 // error checking
167 // defragment
168 // printer ok
169 // network printer ok
170 // printer ok, file
171 // file tree structure
172 // network folder
173 // favorites
174 // old weird folder
175 // network (connect to globe)
176 // add network folder
177 // old htt file
178 // add network
179 // old network terminal thing
180 // screen full
181 // screen empty
182 // folder options: window image with webview
183 // folder options: window image without webview
184 // folder options: open in same window
185 // folder options: open in new window
186 // folder options: click files (link style)
187 // folder options: click files (normal style)
191 // old bin empty
192 // old bin full
193 // network folder
194 // old login (keys)
196 // fax
197 // fax ok
198 // network fax ok
199 // network fax
200 // stop
210 // folder settings
220 // old key users
221 // shutdown (blue circle)
222 // dvd disk
223 // some files
224 // video files
225 // music files
226 // image files
227 // various music/video files
228 // old music disk
229 // hub ?
230 // zip drive
231 // down overlay
232 // down overlay again
233 // other removeable media, same as 8
234 // no disk drive disabled
235 // my documents
236 // my pictures
237 // my music
238 // my videos
239 // msn
240 // delete (webview)
241 // copy (webview)
242 // rename (webview)
243 // files (webview)
244 // globe w/ arrow
245 // printer printing
246 // green arrow (webview)
247 // music (webview)
248 // camera
249 // board
250 // display properties
251 // network images
252 // print images
253 // ok file (webview)
254 // bin empty
255 // green cool arrow (webview)
256 // move
257 // network connection
258 // network drive red thing
259 // network home
260 // write cd (webview)
261 // cd thing (webview)
262 // destroy cd (webview)
263 // help, same as 24
264 // move to folder (webview)
265 // send mail (webview)
266 // move to cd (webview)
267 // shared folder
268 // accessibilty options
269 // users xp
270 // screen palette
271 // add or remove programs
272 // mouse printer
273 // network computers
274 // gear, settings
275 // drive use (piechart)
276 // network calender, syncronise ?
277 // music cpanel
278 // app settings
279 // user xp, same as 269
281 // find files
282 // talking computer
283 // screen keyboard
284 // black thingy
289 // help file
290 // go arrow ie
291 // dvd drive
292 // music+ cd
293 // unknown cd
294 // cd-rom
295 // cd-r
296 // cd-rw
297 // dvd-ram
298 // dvd-r
299 // walkman
300 // cassete drive
301 // smaller cassete drive
302 // cd
303 // red thing
304 // dvd-rom
305 // other removeable media, same as 8 and 233
306 // cards ?
307 // cards ? 2
308 // cards ? 3
309 // camera, same as before
310 // cellphone
311 // network printer globe
312 // jazz drive
313 // zip drive, same as before
314 // pda
315 // scanner
316 // scanner and camera
317 // video camera
318 // dvd-rw, same as before
319 // new folder (red thing)
320 // move to disk (webview)
321 // control panel, third time
322 // start menu favorites (smaller icon)
323 // start menu find (smaller icon)
324 // start menu help (smaller icon)
325 // start menu logoff (smaller icon)
326 // start menu program group (smaller icon)
327 // start menu recent documents (smaller icon)
328 // start menu run (smaller icon)
329 // start menu shutdown (smaller icon)
330 // start menu control panel(smaller icon)
331 // start menu logoff or something (smaller icon)
337 // old lookup phonebook
338 // stop, again
512 // internet explorer
1001 // question
1002 // printer red ok (webview)
1003 // drive ok (webview)
1004 // help file, again
1005 // move file (webview)
1006 // printer file (webview)
1007 // red ok file (webview)
1008 // printer pause (webview)
1009 // printer play (webview)
1010 // shared printer (webview)
1011 // fax, again
8240 // old logoff
16710 // old delete
16715 // old delete
16717 // old delete
16718 // old delete
16721 // old delete
```

Comment: You need two spaces at the end of the line for a line break.

Comment: Where/How did you find this?  Please add that to your answer instead of a comment.